# Multiple regression analysis2

Tags: multiple-regression

I am testing multiple regression models using OLS.  While testing for the OLS assumptions, there was a bit of deviation of normality of residuals as was shown by the residual histograms and normal P-P plots.  All other assumptions were met.  I tried transforming the dependent variable into its logarithm and re-run OLS.  All of the assumption were met after transformation.  Relying on OLS results and backing it up with the OLS with the transformation enough or do I have to run more regressions, taking into account that all my variables are continuous.